# Apply style for cells based on cell number returned by splitting string

Tags: java, xml, xslt, styles

I am new to XSLT. I am working on generating xls based on XSLT template in java. I am able to iterate through and generate xls.

But now I have a column in my xls like Errors which will have values like,
Error (3,5), Error(4)
Error(6)

I need to split above strings and apply style for cells 3,5,4 and 6 in red color in xsl.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Please post a [mcve], including the exact expected result (as code, not image). Also indicate if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: What are `E0007 (6,7), E0008(3)` in the cell ? Please make the question clear to every one.